# two way data binding doesn't work between datePicker directive and controller AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

I made a datepicker directive in Angularjs, and in onSelect callback of datepicker, I update two values from $scope that carries on the model values from the controller.

```
 angular.module("app")
.directive('datePicker', function(){
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            controller: reservationController,
            bindToController: true,
            scope : {
                dateData : "=",
                returnData : "=",
                periodData : "=",
            },
            link : function($scope, $element, $attrs ){
                $($element).datepicker({
                    dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",
                    numberOfMonths: 2,
                    minDate: 0,
                    yearSuffix: ".",
                    showMonthAfterYear:true,
                    dayNames: ['월요일', '화요일', '수요일', '목요일', '금요일', '토요일', '일요일'],
                    dayNamesMin: ['월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토', '일'], 
                    dayNamesShort: ['월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토', '일'], 
                    monthNamesShort: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'],
                    monthNames: ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12'],
                    onSelect : function(date){
                        $scope.dateData = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

                    var date = $scope.dateData;
                    var days = parseInt($scope.periodData);
                    if(days < 30){
                        $scope.returnData = moment(date).add(days, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    }else{
                        var months = days/30
                        $scope.returnData = moment(date).add(months, "months").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    }
                    console.log($scope.returnData);
                }
            });
            $( $element ).datepicker( "setDate", new Date());
        }
    }
})
```

And This is my view

```
<div id="skip" class="container" ng-controller="reservationController as reserveCtrl">
    <input type="text" period-data="reserveCtrl.period" date-picker date-data="reserveCtrl.rent_date" return-data="reserveCtrl.return_date">
    <input type="text" id="" title="retun" ng-model="reserveCtrl.return_date" disabled>
</div>
```

As you see, $scope.returnData is mapped to reserveCtrl.return_date, and $scope.dateData is mapped to reservCtrl.rent_date

So, in onSelect callback, as soon as $scope.dateData is updated, I want to update $scope.returnData by $scope.dateData plus $scope.periodData.
And it show that $scope.returnData is updated on the log.
So. I expect the value is second input to be changed.

However, the model in the controller, reserveCtrl.return_date doesn't seem to be updated because the input remains blank.

I think there is an issue with how I handle scope in callback function.

Please share your criticism, thoughts, and advises.

Comment: If I get your problem correctly, you want data in controller to be updated from directive. But, directive has isolated scope. The changes in directive does not reflect in main controller. But, changes in controller reflects in directive.

Comment: You need to trigger a digest cycle after the model changes via a datepicker select event. Put a $scope.$apply() at the end of the onSelect function

Comment: @IAmDranged   That worked perfectly and it actually fixed many other problems I had.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: sure - glad that was helpfull :)